# Hole suddenly opened in the sink siphon?

Tags: bathroom, drain, sink

Which substance can damage a pipe to the point of opening a hole in the trap?  I used two times that i remember Drano® Max Gel in the past 4 years

Comment: Explain what a "sink siphon" is and how you are using it. Please.

Comment: trap.. sorry the English

Comment: I think is a stainless steel trap siphon

Comment: Please revise your post to include correct terminology and the new information about material.

Comment: It is unlikely that your trap is stainless steel, it is probably chrome plated brass.  **We can not guess at what could have  harmed your brass**. If you have a hole in it you need to replace it, if you need to know how then search this stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the p trap or U bend. The old metal drain lines do wear out because of acids in food, I know  many years back I bought a place that looked good but the chrome plating was all that was left on some of the pipe it developed a small leak when I went to pull it it crumbled like an eggshell. Most of the modern drain cleaners won’t harm pipes. If the cleaner has acid that is a different story and the will damage pipes to tell the truth 2 times is probably not enough for even acid based to cause the problem, things like tomatoes and citrus have more acid in them than drano which is usually a strong base and is great at dissolving organic but really doesn’t hurt pipes.  If the pipes are a shiny silver color they are probably chrome plated brass this is very common and what I have had crumble.